# align 2 input field with a dropdown bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is what I have now, I try multiple method including from but none of them worked for me.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

My code:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<fieldset class="inline-fields">
    <div class = "row col-sm-12">
        <div class = "row col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Designer
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          </ul>
   </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <input type="text" class="form-control form_after input-lg" id="form1" placeholder="email"/>
   <input type="text" class="form-control form_after input-lg" id="form2" placeholder="referal"/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share with us code that you have tried so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4qry43nh/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4qry43nh/1/

Comment: its almost what i need, but how can i set a minimum width to be fully responsive
i can set a minwidth attribut but field will overlap instead of going under each other

https://jsfiddle.net/4qry43nh/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4qry43nh/7/ use `.col-sm-*`. On small screen they will drop and on small and large screens they will be in one row.

Comment: thanks to you, this is my definitive answer, i dont know how can i mark it

Comment: Its ok, Go ahead with your work and finish it. Don't worry about accepting answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `<div class="dropdown">` and 2 input elements

Comment: its better, kind of but here what i have now.. [link (imgur album)](http://imgur.com/a/EPJU9)